# Plotting ellipse intersection points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to plot the intersection points of two ellipses, but they appear to be off.

My code:

```
\documentclass [10pt] {article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 3cm);
            \fill [blue,pattern=north east lines] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
        \end{scope}     
        \draw[red] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
        \draw[blue] (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 3cm);
        \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin,dashed,] (-2.9,-2.9) grid (2.9,2.9);
        \draw[<->,thick] (-3.2,0) -- (3.2,0);
        \draw[<->,thick] (0,-3.2) -- (0,3.2);
        \draw (0.866,0.866) circle (0.5ex)[fill=black]node[anchor=south west, black]{$(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And a picture of the issue:

[image: Plot points misplaced]

And just to make sure I wasn't going crazy, I checked the intersection points on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7B3%7D%2By%5E2%3D1%20and%20x%5E2%2B%5Cfrac%7By%5E2%7D%7B3%7D%3D1).

How can I accurately plot the points I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your math again. I don't know what you really want, but here is one correct solution, which matches the formulas you used on WolframAlpha.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) ellipse (1 and 1.732050808);
            \fill [blue,pattern=north east lines] (0,0) ellipse (1.732050808 and 1);
        \end{scope}     
        \draw[red] (0,0) ellipse (1.732050808 and 1);
        \draw[blue] (0,0) ellipse (1 and 1.732050808);
        \draw[step=1,gray,very thin,dashed,] (-2.9,-2.9) grid (2.9,2.9);
        \draw[<->,thick] (-3.2,0) -- (3.2,0);
        \draw[<->,thick] (0,-3.2) -- (0,3.2);
        \draw (0.866,0.866) circle (0.5ex)[fill=black]node[anchor=south west, black]{$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: ellipse]

Comment: Ah right, the ellipses aren't 3 long, they're √3 long.  My mistake, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `intersections` library of `tikz` to get the real intersection point. I recommend you double-check the math to ensure the calculated coordinates are accurate.

```
\documentclass [10pt] {article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\intp}{sqrt(3)/2.0};
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 3cm);
            \fill [blue,pattern=north east lines] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
        \end{scope}     
        \path[draw,red,name path=p1] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
        \path[draw,blue,name path=p2] (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 3cm);
        \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin,dashed,] (-2.9,-2.9) grid (2.9,2.9);
        \draw[<->,thick] (-3.2,0) -- (3.2,0);
        \draw[<->,thick] (0,-3.2) -- (0,3.2);
        \path [name intersections={of=p1 and p2}];
        \draw (intersection-1) circle (0.5ex)[fill=black]node[anchor=south west, black]{$(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]